# How to create comment section or saveable textarea in R Markdown html document on shared fileserver

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I try to create comment section or a saveable textarea with r markdown and a html output.
The comment section should be very simple. Submit Button and an Input Text Field.

The comments should appear above the Input Fields.

Alternatively the input into textarea could be shown in the textarea after loading the html document by another user.

The case is as followed:

I have many users that use one html document on a file server. Each of the users want to make notes in the html document and any user want to see all notes from the other users. So it has to be possible to save notes and when another user open the file the saved notes should be be filled in the html document. There can´t be a big database with the need to install any software on the file server or the users. I have an one file solution in mind like SQLite. So in the result i dont want to share more than two files on the file server.

Is there a simple way to realize this? Is it even possible? Can I use javascript to save and show the input.

I am thankful for any kind of help with storing the input in the database and writing it in the html document. Unfortunately i´m a beginner in html, sql and javascript.

```
<div id="display"></div>
<div class="comment">
<textarea id="title" type="text "rows="2" cols="100" onkeyup="Allow()" placeholder="write a comment......"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Post" onclick="insert()" style="width:100px;" /></form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var titles = [];
var titleInput = document.getElementById("title");
var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");

function insert () {
titles.push(titleInput.value);
clearAndShow();
}
function clearAndShow ()
{
titleInput.value = "";
messageBox.innerHTML = "";
messageBox.innerHTML += " " + titles.join("<br/> ") + "<br/>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: i'm not clear where `R` comes into play here. i don't know that language but I didn't think it could be used as a server scripting language for handling network requests..

Comment: R can use SQLite databases with the RSQLite package